# Area of the image of a small rectangle under an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

The following question was asked in my complex analysis quiz ( which has been completed) and I was unable to solve this particular question.

> Suppose f(z) is analytic at $z_0$ with $f'(z_0) \neq 0$. Prove that a small rectangle containing $z_0$ and having an area A is mapped onto a figure whose approximate area is $|f'(z_0)|^2A$.

So, I assumed a small rectangle containing $z_0$ has vertices equal to $ z_0+ a_1 -a_2 , z_0- a_1 -a_2 , z_0 +a_1+ b_1 , z_0 -a_1 +b_1$ , so I got the area $2a_1 \times ( b_1 +a_2)$. But I am unable to use small over the length or how to  co-orelate with area $f(z_0 + a_1 -a_2)- f( z_0 +a_1 +b_1)  \times f(z_0 +a_1  - a_2)- f(z_0 -a_1 - a_2)$.

can you please help me with completing this question ?

Comment: this is the basic calculus 3 change of variable formula applied to complex analysis since the jacobian of $f$ (smooth function from a domain of the plane to the plane) is $|f'(z)|^2$ when $f$ is holomorphic

Comment: @Conrad Can you please elaborate on this? I am not able to understand.

Comment: If we were talking about circles, this would just be a consequence of having $f(z)-f(z_0) \approx f'(z_0) (z-z_0)$.

Comment: Do you know the usual formula from calculus that gives the change of variables formula in 2 dimensions?